# Trying to print a shape but don't know how to add the spaces

Tags: python

I'm trying to create the following shape.

```
    *
   **
  ***
 ****
*****
```

My code currently creates this shape.

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

With this code.

```
n = 5
s = ' '
for i in range(1,n+1):
    for j in range(1,i+1):
        print("*", end="")
    print()
```

I've tried various methods but none seem to work. One the ways I tried to do it was by trying to insert an additional print statement like the one below but that did not work either.

```
n = 5
s = ' '
for i in range(1,n+1):
    for j in range(1,i+1):
        print(' '*(n-i))
        print("*", end="")
    print()
```

Can I get a hint as to how to go about printing the shape that I'm trying to get?

Comment: `for i in range(1,n+1): print(' '*(n-i), "*"*i)`

Comment: "One the ways I tried to do it was by trying to insert an additional print statement like the one below but that did not work either." Okay, so what exactly happened when you tried this? You just got extra blank lines, right? Actually those lines are not blank - they must have spaces on them, because you asked for spaces to be printed, right? Okay, now try to think logically about the code. Where the code says `print("*", end="")`, what does that mean? In particular, what does the `end=""` part mean? Would it be useful to have that in the `print(' '*(n-i))` line? Why or why not?

Comment: @Marat that will give one extra space on each line (and it cannot be *properly* removed by altering the arithmetic) - do you see why?

Comment: Anyway, we don't really deal in "hints" here. Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel just add `sep=''` to print parameters

Answer (score 0):

Use builtins for this, don't write it from scratch.

```py
n = 5
for i in range(1, n+1):
    chars = "*" * i
    print(chars.rjust(n))
```

Check out [`str.rjust()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rjust)

Answer (score 0):

You only need to use one loop to achieve this, I also recommend getting familiar with f strings in python and try something like the following:

```
n = 5
s = ' '
t = "*"
for i in range(1,n+1):
     print(f"{s*(n-i)}{t*i}") 
print()
```

This way, you can multiply the string by whatever amount you need to be printed on that line, in this case the value is n-i for the empty spaces and i for the asterisks.

For more info on F strings, try [here](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)